# Connect to Azure VM on 8080 port

Tags: azure, azure-networking

I am not able to connect to azure vm on port 8080 through IIS using Http. However i can reach out to default 80 port. I have already configured NSG with CIDR block pointing to my workstation's public ip address. any thoughts?

Actually my TFS is hosted on Azure VM which uses 8080 port by default.

Comment: Please edit your question to show your inbound NSG rules. Also, what about your firewall settings?

Answer (score 2):

Your question doesn't have a great deal of detail, but things to check:

1. Can you actually connect to that port from a browser running on the Azure VM its self, if not then this is an issue with the VM configuration or application
2. Check the Windows firewall on the VM its self, does it allow inbound access on port 80?
3. Check your NSG, make sure that your rules allow inbound access. Start with less restrictive rule and narrow down as required

Comment: Thank you for kicking me to look at the Windows Firewall!  THAT was *my* problem.  This is a POC so I simply disabled the firewall.  I was lazy.

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot this issue, you can do the follow checks:
1. Make sure you can browse 127.0.0.1 and port 8080 on the Azure VM, if not, please check the configuration of the IIS.
2. If you can browse the port 8080 on the Azure VM, then you can use your workstation to **telnet** the port 8080, for test you can turn off the windows firewall. After the test completed, turn on the windows firewall.
3. If the windows firewall turn off and can't telnet the port 8080, you should check the NSG settings (inbound rules), make sure the port 8080 is allow, then check the subnet firewall settings, and you workstation firewall settings.
Besides, to troubleshoot this issue more efficiently, you may try to perform a network capture on the Azure VM. Then you are able to find the detailed behavior of the VM, which is very useful for troubleshooting.